# Find two real numbers whose difference is S an whose product is a minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

I don't know what to do. Please explain?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Also, your problem has multiple methods of solution, and we need to know which methods are appropriate for your current level.

Comment: Since you posted pre calculus for a calculus problem,  can you attempt this simple differentiation?: $ x- y = S. $ Now maximize $ x\, y$. Can you eliminate one variable?

Answer (score 3):

You want $x-y=S$ and $xy$ is minimum.  Well $y=x-S$ so you need to minimize $x(x-S)$ which is a parabola.  Do you know how to find the minimum of a parabola?